# 8 Марта или 8 марта. В полном названии праздника

Tags: прописная, строчная

Международный женский день 8 Марта или 8 марта. Здесь же полное название, зачем повышать март. Я так понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

> В названиях праздников с начальной цифрой название месяца пишется с
> большой буквы: 1 Мая (Первое мая), 8 Марта (Восьмое марта).
> В отличие
> от названий праздников календарные даты пишутся с маленькой буквы.
> Ср.: **Поздравляю с 8 Марта**!, но: **8 марта мы отмечаем Международный
> женский день**.

Источник: [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/74-rubric-87).

Comment: Это я видела. Но «поздравляем с Международным женским днем 8 марта...». В этом предложении, например...Склоняюсь, что с маленькой...

Comment: @flossyU по-моему, это вообще тавтология. Два наименования одного праздника. По идее должно писаться через тире, которое заменяет слово "то есть": *Поздравляем с Международным женским днём — 8 Марта!*